# Jmeter - Extract id from json

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm using Json path extractor to fetch id from the json

```
getid = $.id
```

But it is not fetching any value. The json is:

```
Json
..Data
....abcd = dlkf
....id = 038443
....ksdhf= ofkj
..success = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following JSONPath Extractor configuration:

- Destination Variable Name: any name of your choice, i.e. `getid`
- JSONPath Expression: `$..id[0]`

Refer extracted value as `${getid}` where required.

References:

- [JSONPath Extractor Documentation](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/)
- [JSONPath Syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e1)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") - installation instructions and XPath to JSONPath mappings

Answer (score 0):

Please share what value do you want to fetch from JSON? Is it 038443?
I believe issue is not with with JSON extractor but the regular expression you have written. Please share more details so a solution could be proposed.